# disabling animation while hovering

Tags: jquery

Below I have some code which basically animates a div from the bottom of the page to the top. When I hover over the div I want the animation to stop immediately and give the div an opacity value of 0.25. When the mouse leaves the div I want the animation to continue.

Right now the animation doesn't stop and the opacity value is given after the animation is finished and not immediately which is what I want.

So how do I get the result I want?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#bubble{ 
border-radius:20px;
margin:3px; 
width:40px; 
height:40px;
position:absolute;
left:0px; 
top:1000px;
background:green; 
display:none; 
}
</style>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bubble"></div>
<script>
function runIt() {
$('#bubble').show(0);
$('#bubble').animate({top:'-=1000px',},5000);
$('#bubble').animate({top:'+=1000px',},0);
$('#bubble').hide("normal", runIt);
}

runIt();

$('#bubble').hover(function() {
  $('#bubble').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
  }, 500, function() {});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [jQuery pause/resume plugin](https://raw.github.com/tobia/Pause/master/jquery.pause.min.js) that does exactly what your looking for.

**[See this fiddle as an example](http://jsfiddle.net/HemUe/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

In the hover event, you'll want to call .[stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)(true, false). Then in the exit function (currently empty), you'll need to restart the animation from the current position.

```
<script>
function runIt() {
$('#bubble').show(0);
$('#bubble').animate({top:'-=1000px'},5000);
$('#bubble').animate({top:'+=1000px'},0);
$('#bubble').hide("normal", runIt);
}

runIt();

$('#bubble').hover(function() {
  $(this).stop(true, false);
  $(this).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
  }, 500);
}, function() {
  runIt();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop). You could use that to stop any animations running on a selected element (and optionally make it instantaneously go to the animation's logical end) on the `mouseover` and restart the animation on the `mouseout` components of `hover()`.

```
$('#bubble').animate({ 
    // blah
}).hover(function() {
    // stop animation
    $(this).stop().css({ opacity : 0.25 });
}, function () {
    // continue animation
    $(this).css({ opacity : 1.0 }).animate({ /* blah */ });
});
```

However, looking at your code, you're using incremental animation (i.e. using `+=1000px` instead of something fixed like `1000px`). Because of that, you'll have to keep track of the animation's progress somehow and apply an adjusted incremental on the `mouseout`.

For example, if `#bubble` is animating, and then you hover on it, you should be able to determine that it's already moved `300px` for example, and call an adjusted `.animate({ top : '-=700px' })` on the continue.

If you were using fixed values for animation, it shouldn't be a problem to just call the original animation again on the continue.